# How to add ajax url to js using wp_add_inline_script()?

Tags: ajax, wp-localize-script

I usually enable ajax in a js script by using *wp_localize_script* like this

```
wp_localize_script( 'map-scripts', 'ajax_info', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

but now I see it is best practice to use *wp_add_inline_script*, which I find harder to use.

I am not able to pass an array with this method. I tried the following but it does not look the same:

```
$ajax_arr = array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
$ajax_json = json_encode($ajax_arr);
$ajax_info  = 'ajax_info = '.json_encode($ajax_json).';';
wp_add_inline_script( 'map-scripts', $ajax_info, 'before' );
```

Do you know the proper way to do it?

Comment: Where did you see that it was best practice to use that function?

Comment: have you considered using the REST API for ajax instead of the old admin ajax file?

Comment: @JacobPeattie https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/#more-information says  wp_add_inline_script() was introduced in WordPress Version 4.5, and is now the best practice for that use case

Comment: @TomJNowell yes! I have used it a couple of times, do you recommend it? I like it, but there is not as much documentation/community on it.

Comment: Personally I see no reason to use `admin-ajax.php` while the REST API exists

Comment: @TomJNowell ok i will try to learn it deeper. But the question here is on how to pass an array with the function wp_add_inline_script

Comment: I agree, that's why I left a comment instead of a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone still needs it:

```php
wp_add_inline_script(
  'map-scripts',
  'const ajax_info = ' . json_encode(array(
      'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
   )),
  'before'
);
```

but, it's good practice to use nonce as well for better security:

```php
wp_add_inline_script(
  'map-scripts',
  'const ajax_info = ' . json_encode(array(
      'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('your_nonce_handler'), //the more specific the better
      'your_other_item' => "some additional data", //etc.. 
   )),
  'before'
);
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/